# Bloomer Dropdown Menu not trigger (React)

Tags: reactjs, bulma

i install the bloomer and bulma. However i already import the dropdown. but whenever i click the dropdown menu is not showing. Can someone help me why? Thank you

This is the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-tree-9vvf6?file=/src/App.js:34-130

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open issue about it on [github](https://github.com/AlgusDark/bloomer/issues/134)

It means that you can start your contribution in open source and try to solve it or just use this workaround:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import {
  DropdownContent,
  Dropdown,
  DropdownItem,
  DropdownTrigger,
  Button,
  Icon,
  DropdownMenu
} from "bloomer";
import "bulma/css/bulma.min.css";

export default function App() {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Dropdown isActive={isActive}>
        <DropdownTrigger onClick={(prev) => setIsActive(!prev)}>
          <Button isOutlined aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu">
            <span>Dropdown button</span>
            <Icon icon="angle-down" isSize="small" />
          </Button>
        </DropdownTrigger>
        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownContent>
            <DropdownItem href="#">First item</DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem href="#" isActive>
              Second item
            </DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem href="#">Third item</DropdownItem>
          </DropdownContent>
        </DropdownMenu>
      </Dropdown>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-morning-0utb9?file=/src/App.js